# Build nested object array from recursive function

Tags: javascript

How would i utilize my getChildren() function to create a larger function which takes my two main arrays `objs` and `objRefs` and outputs a single array of objs demonstrating their parent/child relationship.

here are the two main data arrays

```
const objs = [
    { name: "Kevin", age: 5, id: 1 },
    { name: "Matt", age: 53, id: 5 },
    { name: "Marry", age: 30, id: 2 },
    { name: "Leslie", age: 21, id: 3 },
    { name: "Sarah", age: 46, id: 4 },
    { name: "Heather", age: 37, id: 6 },
    { name: "Cory", age: 19, id: 7 },
]

const objRefs = [
    { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 7 }, // cory child of matt
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 6 }, // matt root
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 4 }, // sarah root
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 5 }, // heather root
    { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 3 }, // leslie child of matt
    { parent_id: 4, obj_id: 2 }, // mary child of sarah
    { parent_id: 3, obj_id: 1 }, // kevin child of leslie
]
```

My goal is to run a function called `getFamilyTree()` which would return me this...

```
const tree = [
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Matt",
        age: 53,
        children:[ 
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Leslie",
                age: 21,
                children:[ 
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "Kevin",
                        age: 5,
                        children:[ ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                name: "Cory",
                age: 19,
                children:[ ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "Heather",
        age: 37,
        children:[ ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Sarah",
        age: 46,
        children:[ 
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Marry",
                age: 30,
                children:[ ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have a function that returns me all the children for the given parent node id, but im not sure how structure a function to return me the entire tree like my example.

```
function getChildren(parent_id) {
    let children = []
    for (var i = 0; i < objRefs.length; i++) {
        const ref = objRefs[i]
        if (ref.parent_id === parent_id) {
            const obj = objs.find(obj => {
                return obj.id === ref.obj_id
            })
            children.push(obj)
        }
    }
    return children
}

function getFamilyTree() {
    let result = []
    ... // build recursive family tree
    return result 
}
```

Comment: do you need to use a recursive function?

Comment: no. just figured it would be necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a recursive function to construct that.

To get a reasonable time complexity, store all the `objs` to a Map or something (if the `id`s are sequential, even an array will work) keyed by `id`. Then, just iterate over `objRefs` and construct the relations appropriately:

```js
const objs = [
    { name: "Kevin", age: 5, id: 1 },
    { name: "Matt", age: 53, id: 5 },
    { name: "Marry", age: 30, id: 2 },
    { name: "Leslie", age: 21, id: 3 },
    { name: "Sarah", age: 46, id: 4 },
    { name: "Heather", age: 37, id: 6 },
    { name: "Cory", age: 19, id: 7 
},
]

const objRefs = [
    { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 7 }, // cory child of matt
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 6 }, // matt root
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 4 }, // sarah root
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 5 }, // heather root
    { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 3 }, // leslie child of matt
    { parent_id: 4, obj_id: 2 }, // mary child of sarah
    { parent_id: 3, obj_id: 1 }, // kevin child of leslie
]


function getFamilyTree(objs, objRefs){

    const tree = []

    const map = new Map(
        objs.map(e => [e.id, { ...e, children: [] }])
    )

    for(const {parent_id, obj_id} of objRefs){
        if(parent_id === null){
            tree.push(map.get(obj_id))
        }else{
            map.get(parent_id).children.push(map.get(obj_id))
        }
    }

    return tree
}

const tree = getFamilyTree(objs, objRefs)

console.log(tree)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you even need the `getChildren` function to actually build your tree. Using Maps instead could be useful:

```js
const objs = [
    { name: "Kevin", age: 5, id: 1 },
    { name: "Matt", age: 53, id: 5 },
    { name: "Marry", age: 30, id: 2 },
    { name: "Leslie", age: 21, id: 3 },
    { name: "Sarah", age: 46, id: 4 },
    { name: "Heather", age: 37, id: 6 },
    { name: "Cory", age: 19, id: 7 },
]

const objRefs = [
    { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 7 }, // cory child of matt
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 6 }, // matt root
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 4 }, // sarah root
    { parent_id: null, obj_id: 5 }, // heather root
    { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 3 }, // leslie child of matt
    { parent_id: 4, obj_id: 2 }, // mary child of sarah
    { parent_id: 3, obj_id: 1 }, // kevin child of leslie
]

function getFamillyTree(){
  const nodes = new Map()

  // Preparing the data nodes
  objs.forEach(elt => nodes.set(elt.id, {...elt, children: [], root: false}))

  // Linking the nodes to make the parent <-> children relations
  objRefs.filter(rel => !!rel.parent_id).forEach(rel => {
    const parent = nodes.get(rel.parent_id)
    parent.children.push(nodes.get(rel.obj_id))
  })
  
  // Marking the roots
  objRefs.filter(rel => rel.parent_id === null).forEach(rel => {
    const obj = nodes.get(rel.obj_id)
    obj.root = true
  })
  return Array.from(nodes.values()).filter(obj => obj.root)
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(getFamillyTree(), null, 4))
```

Edit: This answer can be slightly off, because as Nina stated in a comment on the question, OP seems to ask for an explicitly recursive solution, leaving this here for reference.

Comment: why do you say this is slightly off? You don't have to do recursive function if it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some object as reference to the persons and their relations and map the nodes with their children.

```js
const
    getChildren = parent => (references[parent] || []).map(id => ({
        ...nodes[id],
         children: getChildren(id)
    })),
    people = [{ name: "Kevin", age: 5, id: 1 }, { name: "Matt", age: 53, id: 5 }, { name: "Marry", age: 30, id: 2 }, { name: "Leslie", age: 21, id: 3 }, { name: "Sarah", age: 46, id: 4 }, { name: "Heather", age: 37, id: 6 }, { name: "Cory", age: 19, id: 7 }],
    children = [{ parent_id: 5, obj_id: 7 }, { parent_id: null, obj_id: 6 }, { parent_id: null, obj_id: 4 }, { parent_id: null, obj_id: 5 }, { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 3 }, { parent_id: 4, obj_id: 2 }, { parent_id: 3, obj_id: 1 }],
    nodes = Object.fromEntries(people.map(o => [o.id, o])),
    references = children.reduce((r, { parent_id, obj_id }) => ((r[parent_id] ??= []).push(obj_id), r), {}),
    tree = getChildren(null);
    
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach with a single loop of `children`.

```js
const
    getTree = (people, children, root) => {
        const
            nodes = Object.fromEntries(people.map(o => [o.id, o])),
            t = {};

       children.forEach(({ parent_id: p, obj_id: id }) => 
           ((t[p] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(Object.assign(t[id] ??= {}, nodes[id]))
       );
       return t[root].children;
    },
    people = [{ name: "Kevin", age: 5, id: 1 }, { name: "Matt", age: 53, id: 5 }, { name: "Marry", age: 30, id: 2 }, { name: "Leslie", age: 21, id: 3 }, { name: "Sarah", age: 46, id: 4 }, { name: "Heather", age: 37, id: 6 }, { name: "Cory", age: 19, id: 7 }],
    children = [{ parent_id: 5, obj_id: 7 }, { parent_id: null, obj_id: 6 }, { parent_id: null, obj_id: 4 }, { parent_id: null, obj_id: 5 }, { parent_id: 5, obj_id: 3 }, { parent_id: 4, obj_id: 2 }, { parent_id: 3, obj_id: 1 }],
    tree = getTree(people, children, null);
    
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```